# How to automate change similar variable names?

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, automated-refactoring

How to automate change names of many variables in active document or whole project? In my project I have plenty of variabables which have generic type IReadRepository.

I want variable of this type:

```
IDTOReadRepository<LongDocument, LongDocumentDTO> 
IDTOReadRepository<Employee, EmployeeDTO>
```

to have name like this:

```
_longDocumentReadRepository
_employeeReadRepository
```

Now I have many names which aren't following this pattern and I need to refactorcode, it will take much time to change them one by one. I'm using visual studio and C#.

Comment: How many instances do you need to change?

Comment: @Ian hundreds or more

Comment: What you want to do, to incorporate the type name into the variable name, is viewed by many as a code smell. If you really want to do this, I see nothing better than applying the Rename refactoring to each variable.